# VS Code - JSON Schema cache

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I have just upgraded to TypeScript 1.5 (no longer beta) and in doing so, would like to take advantage of the json schema helpers in VS Code.

When configuring tsconfig.json the only module options are `commonjs` and `amd` meaning that `umd` and `system` are missing based upon this: http://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig

My questions is how do I get VS Code to refresh it's cache of the schema?

FYI, I have tried overriding the URL in the settings and changing it back as well as restarting VS Code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My questions is how do I get VS Code to refresh it's cache of the schema?

The schema is actually hardcoded in a file called `jsonWorker.js` (my file path is `C:\Users\basaratsyed\AppData\Local\Code\app-0.1.2\resources\app\client\vs\languages\json\jsonWorker.js`) which is minified. Here is the relevant code *beautified* by atom-beautify https://atom.io/packages/atom-beautify :

```
this.addPreloadedFileSchema("http://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig", {
            title: n.localize("vs_languages_json_jsonSchemaService", 110),
            $schema: "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
            type: "object",
            default: {
                compilerOptions: {
                    target: "ES5",
                    module: "commonjs"
                }
            },
            properties: {
                compilerOptions: {
                    type: "object",
                    description: n.localize("vs_languages_json_jsonSchemaService", 111),
                    properties: {
                        charset: {
                            description: n.localize("vs_languages_json_jsonSchemaService", 112),
                            type: "string"
                        },
                        declaration: {
                            description: n.localize("vs_languages_json_jsonSchemaService", 113),
                            type: "boolean"
                        },
                        diagnostics: {
                            description: n.localize("vs_languages_json_jsonSchemaService", 114),
                            type: "boolean"
                        },
                        emitBOM: {
                            description: n.localize("vs_languages_json_jsonSchemaService", 115),
                            type: "boolean"
                        },
                        inlineSourceMap: {
                            description: n.localize("vs_languages_json_jsonSchemaService", 116),
                            type: "number"
                        },
                        inlineSources: {
                            description: n.localize("vs_languages_json_jsonSchemaService", 117),
                            type: "number"
                        },
                        listFiles: {
                            description: n.localize("vs_languages_json_jsonSchemaService", 118),
                            type: "boolean"
                        },
                        locale: {
                            description: n.localize("vs_languages_json_jsonSchemaService", 119),
                            type: "string"
                        },
                        mapRoot: {
                            description: n.localize("vs_languages_json_jsonSchemaService", 120),
                            type: "string",
                            format: "uri"
                        },
                        module: {
                            description: n.localize("vs_languages_json_jsonSchemaService", 121),
                            enum: ["commonjs", "amd"]
                        },
                        newLine: {
                            description: n.localize("vs_languages_json_jsonSchemaService", 122),
                            type: "boolean"
                        },
                        noEmit: {
                            description: n.localize("vs_languages_json_jsonSchemaService", 123),
                            type: "boolean"
                        },
                        noEmitOnError: {
                            description: n.localize("vs_languages_json_jsonSchemaService", 124),
                            type: "boolean"
                        },
                        noEmitHelpers: {
                            description: n.localize("vs_languages_json_jsonSchemaService", 125),
                            type: "boolean"
                        },
                        noImplicitAny: {
                            description: n.localize("vs_languages_json_jsonSchemaService", 126),
                            type: "boolean"
                        },
                        noLib: {
                            description: n.localize("vs_languages_json_jsonSchemaService", 127),
                            type: "boolean"
                        },
                        noResolve: {
                            type: "boolean"
                        },
                        out: {
                            description: n.localize("vs_languages_json_jsonSchemaService", 128),
                            type: "string",
                            format: "uri"
                        },
                        outDir: {
                            description: n.localize("vs_languages_json_jsonSchemaService", 129),
                            type: "string",
                            format: "uri"
                        },
                        preserveConstEnums: {
                            description: n.localize("vs_languages_json_jsonSchemaService", 130),
                            type: "boolean"
                        },
                        removeComments: {
                            description: n.localize("vs_languages_json_jsonSchemaService", 131),
                            type: "boolean"
                        },
                        rootDir: {
                            description: n.localize("vs_languages_json_jsonSchemaService", 132),
                            type: "boolean"
                        },
                        sourceMap: {
                            description: n.localize("vs_languages_json_jsonSchemaService", 133),
                            type: "boolean"
                        },
                        sourceRoot: {
                            description: n.localize("vs_languages_json_jsonSchemaService", 134),
                            type: "string",
                            format: "uri"
                        },
                        suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors: {
                            description: n.localize("vs_languages_json_jsonSchemaService", 135),
                            type: "boolean"
                        },
                        target: {
                            description: n.localize("vs_languages_json_jsonSchemaService", 136),
                            enum: ["ES3", "ES5", "ES6", "es3", "es5", "es6"],
                            default: "ES3"
                        }
                    }
                },
                files: {
                    type: "array",
                    description: n.localize("vs_languages_json_jsonSchemaService", 137),
                    items: {
                        type: "string",
                        format: "uri"
                    }
                }
            }
        })
```

And a bit more focused in:

```
module: {
    description: n.localize("vs_languages_json_jsonSchemaService", 121),
    enum: ["commonjs", "amd"]
},
```

If you change it

```
module: {
    description: n.localize("vs_languages_json_jsonSchemaService", 121),
    enum: ["commonjs", "amd", "umd", "system"]
},
```

And then restart vs code it works

[image]

Note that after you beautify the js file VS Code still works fine ;)

Answer (score 2):

1. I failed to find the official solution to clear such cache... but I think the command "Reload Window" would work.
2. "Changes to the schema file are not reflected" is a bug https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/13897 , and has been fixed. but as far as I know, it requires the name of the schema file to be end with ".json", any other extension name (such as ".schema" in my case), even explicity associated to json in settings, would not trigger the refresh event to make your changes work immediately.

Comment: I had used the extension jsonc for my schemas because I wanted to include comments. Swapping to the json extension resulted in changes to the schema files being reflected in the JSON documents again.

Answer (score 1):

There is a new command that you could trigger before loading your schema:

> JSON clear schema cache command
>
> A new command `JSON: Clear schema cache` clears the cache of previously
> downloaded schemas.

- from https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_64.md#json-clear-schema-cache-command

`await vscode.commands.executeCommand('json.clearCache');`